# Creating a child node to a child node in vb.net with TreeView

Tags: xml, vb.net, treenode

I'm trying to programatically add childnodes to my TreeView.

Initially I did them manually using `TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes(0).Nodes(0)`...
which naturally starts to look nasty, but will also not work when I try to append records to records.

My current code will take all my code and place then at the root level because the function used `TreeView1.Nodes.Add(tn)` is technically at the root code wise. How can I make it dynamic where I will not have to manually code it (avoiding `TreeView1.Nodes(0).Nodes(0).Nodes(0)`...)

The order is:

```
Main
 |_ Screen
     |_ Msg
     |_ A
     |_ B
     |_ C
     |_ D
```

VB.net

```
    add_child_node(doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Main").Name)

    Private Sub add_child_node(NodeName As String)
        Dim tn As New TreeNode(NodeName)
        'TreeView1.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(tn)
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(tn)
    End Sub
```

XML

```
    <Main>  
      <Screen ID="0" ParentID="-1">
        <Msg></Msg>
        <A ChildID="1"></A>
        <B ChildID=""></B>
        <C ChildID=""></C>
        <D ChildID=""></D>
      </Screen>
    </Main>
```

Comment: You can put the nodes in variables. mainNode = TreeView1.Nodes(0), screenNode = mainNode.Nodes(0), msgNode = screenNode.Nodes(0)

Comment: 1. Note that the methods to add a TreeNode (Add, Insert) all return the node that was added. You can use that resulting node's Nodes collection to add children.

Comment: 2. Trees are a great time to use recursion.

Answer (score 0):

### TreeNode : How it works ?

```
Dim ScreenNode As TreeNode
Dim MyChildNode As TreeNode = TreeView1.Nodes.Add("<Main>")

    'TreeView
    ' |_ <Main> <- MyChildNode points to this Node

MyChildNode = MyChildNode.Nodes.Add("<Screen>")
ScreenNode = MyChildNode

    'TreeView
    ' |_ <Main>
    '     |_ <Screen> <- MyChildNode and ScreenNode both are pointing to this Node

MyChildNode = MyChildNode.Parent

    'TreeView
    ' |_ <Main> <- MyChildNode points to this Node
    '     |_ <Screen> <- ScreenNode points to this Node

MyChildNode = MyChildNode.Nodes.Add("<Screen2>")

    'TreeView
    ' |_ <Main>
    '     |_ <Screen> <- ScreenNode points to this Node
    '     |_ <Screen2> <- MyChildNode points to this Node

MyChildNode = TreeView1.Nodes.Add("<Main2>")

    'TreeView
    ' |_ <Main>
    ' |   |_ <Screen> <- ScreenNode points to this Node
    ' |   |_ <Screen2>
    ' |_ <Main2> <- MyChildNode points to this Node

Dim CurrentNode As TreeNode
For i As Int32 = 1 To 5
    CurrentNode = MyChildNode.Nodes.Add(i.ToString())
Next
MyChildNode = CurrentNode

    'TreeView
    ' |_ <Main>
    ' |   |_ <Screen> <- ScreenNode points to this Node
    ' |   |_ <Screen2>
    ' |_ <Main2>
    '     |_ <1>
    '     |_ <2>
    '     |_ <3>
    '     |_ <4>
    '     |_ <5> <- MyChildNode points to this Node

ScreenNode.Nodes.Add("<Msg>")

    'TreeView
    ' |_ <Main>
    ' |   |_ <Screen> <- ScreenNode points to this Node
    ' |       |_ <Msg>
    ' |   |_ <Screen2>
    ' |_ <Main2>
    '     |_ <1>
    '     |_ <2>
    '     |_ <3>
    '     |_ <4>
    '     |_ <5> <- MyChildNode points to this Node
```

---

### Recursivity !

```
Private Function BuildTreeOf(ByRef CurrentXMLNode As SomeXMLNode) As TreeNode
    Dim CurrentTreeNode As New TreeNode(CurrentXMLNode.Name)

    For Each ChildXML As SomeXMLNode In CurrentXMLNode.Children
        CurrentTreeNode.Add(BuildTreeOf(ChildXML))
    Next

    Return CurrentTreeNode
End Function

' Call :

TreeView1.BeginUpdate()
TreeView1.Nodes.Add(BuildTreeOf(tn))
' Where tn is the topmost parent of your XML data as SomeXMLNode.
TreeView1.EndUpdate()
```

I've put a placeholder object of type SomeXMLNode supposed to have a .Children Property which is a (sorted) collection of objects of the same type as I use my own XML Parser and I've lost track of the native dotNet Objects about XML. Try to adapt the above using the XML objects you're manipulating.